# Cleanup the cheat-sheet questions

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

There are 76 questions tagged [cheat-sheet](/questions/tagged/cheat-sheet) or [cheatsheet](/questions/tagged/cheatsheet) or [reference-card](/questions/tagged/reference-card). Most of theses questions are off topic because they are asking for links to off-site cheat sheets. The answers are usually just a lists of links which becomes out of date quickly. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/823672/objective-c-cheat-sheet) is a typical example.

I suggest we close/delete any of the off-topic [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cheatsheet+or+cheat-sheet+or+reference-card) and burn the tags to discourage other people from asking such questions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm went through the list of questions, voting to close each and every question that asks for a cheat-sheet or reference card resource. Many are already closed, my vote tally should stretch a fair distance, provided others jump in and help too; just 6 or so others helping out will clear these out in no time!

The following search lists all <strike>54</strike> <strike>53</strike> <strike>52</strike> <strike>51</strike> <strike>45</strike> <strike>44</strike> **zero** questions still open:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcheat-sheet%5D+or+%5Bcheatsheet%5D+or+%5Breference-card%5D+closed%3Ano

For most of these, voting to close as "Off-Topic" -> "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource" is the best option, but for some Too Broad (asking many questions) or Primarily Opinion Based (asking for experience and personal tips) are applicable as well.

I've removed the `cheat-sheet` / `cheatsheet` / `reference-card` tags from any that are not off-topic, as for those the tag is used as a meta-tag and no meaning is lost when the tag is removed.

I've voted on all remaining posts now; the rest is up to everyone else. So chip in, the list is dwindling fast!

### Update: No more open questions left

*Yay us!* Now that the resource-request questions are all closed, we can clean up the tags!

I got rid of the [cheatsheet](/questions/tagged/cheatsheet) and [reference-card](/questions/tagged/reference-card) tags altogether; they were mere synonyms of [cheat-sheet](/questions/tagged/cheat-sheet).

I also removed the [cheat-sheet](/questions/tagged/cheat-sheet) tag from all posts that had other relevant tags. We are now left with just <strike>**four**</strike> **three** posts that all ask for a cross-language cheet sheet, *or* ask for a tool to *create* a cheat sheet. We could perhaps delete those 3, but do check if there is anything of value left in the answers.

The following 2 are just requests for external resources:

- <strike>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18936/good-cheat-sheets</strike>
- <strike>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199145/creating-a-programming-cheat-sheet</strike>

and can be deleted as far as I am concerned; the top answer on the first is just an external link, for example.

The last one was a reasonably good question, albeit one that is perhaps primarily opinion-based. I'd be fine with it surviving, closed:

- <strike>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500647/are-cheatsheets-useful</strike>

Comment: Good, we can add them to the very short and quickly cleared close vote queue.  trollface.jpg

Comment: @JeffGohlke: The search link in my answer gives you a nice and short list. Only 54 to go!

Comment: @MartijnPieters Unrelated side question - is there a way to sort them by close votes via the search field? Or would the SQL query be needed for this? Might make a good meta question.

Comment: @JoshC: You can only select them by open status, you cannot query for the number of votes, no.